# Comparison of two arrays not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript

As the title says I am trying to compare the content of two arrays. The second array can consist of multiple values and it is not necessarily the same values being generated in the first array. The second array consists of a bunch string values. My application works as follows. Everytime I click a button it generates an array of string elements. Before pushing this to the second array, I want to check whether or not this array contains all of the elements (This is where it fails). If so, I want to remove the following elements from the second array. The second array must contain all of the elements from the first array for it to be removed.

If not, push the elements to the second array. I know that the code for the button and that the button is generating some random strings when clicked on, so I wont include this functionality in my question. This is my code so far.

```
       compare(array1, array2) {
                return array1.every(i => array2.includes(i));
       }

       check(array1, array2) {
            if (compare(array1, array2)) {
                this.remove(array1);
            } else {
                this.add(array1, array2);
            }
        }

       add(array1, array2) {
            for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                array2.push(array1[i]);
            }
        }

        remove(array1, array2) {
            for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                    if (array1[i] === (array2[j])) {
                        array2.splice(elements[i], 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Do you see any obvious mistakes? Sometimes it works, but when the second array is large it doesnt work.

Comment: The first problem I see is that in `remove`, only `array1` is getting passed in, although `array2` is also getting referenced.

Comment: `array2.splice(elements[i], 1);` the signature of splice is `Array#splice(index, numberOfItemsToRemove, ...itemsToInject)` I don't think that `elements[i]` contains an index. Second, your loop. You iterate over an Array while removing items from the very same Array your iterating over; and you don't compensate for that.

Comment: Can you explain further, Thomas?

Comment: @Nick55 try this: `var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) array.splice(i, 1);` this "should" remove every item in the Array, right? But check the result and try to understand why this happens. Your code has the same problem.